# Interval scheduling: How to track the schedules tried so far?

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have spent countless hours trying to figure this out with no success. The problem I'm trying to solve is finding the **paths** (i.e. the schedules of tasks) that will provide the most value. See [Interval scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling).

In the chart below, you can see that Task 1 has a value of 5 (the red number), begins at `t = 1`, and ends at `t = 4`. Task 2 has a value of 1, begins at `t = 3`, and ends at `t = 5`, etc.

[image]

You cannot do any tasks that overlap. Meaning if I choose to do task 1, I cannot do task 2, 3, or 5 but I CAN do 4 since it starts directly after 1 finishes.

So the best possible result would be to do task 1, task 4, then task 8. That would be worth 13 points.

I can calculate the maximum value with the code below:

```
class Tasks:
    def __init__(self, task_id, earnings, start_time, end_time):
        self.task_id = task_id
        self.earnings = earnings
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time
        self.duration = (end_time - start_time)


def value(n):
    n_value = task_list[n-1].earnings
    return n_value


def prev(n):
    n_start = task_list[n-1].start_time
    n_prev = 0

    # cycles through list of tasks
    for i, task in enumerate(task_list):
        # if n_prev has been changed from its initial value of 0
        if n_prev > 0:
            # finds the latest task endtime that's less than or equal to the start of n
            if n_start >= task.end_time > task_list[n_prev-1].end_time:
                n_prev = task.task_id
        else:
            # else, n_prev is 0 and assigns it to the first task that ends before n starts
            if n_start >= task.end_time:
                n_prev = task.task_id

    return n_prev


def get_max(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0

    # the earnings for doing the task
    do_task = value(n) + get_max(prev(n))

    # the earnings for not doing the task
    dont_do_task = get_max(n-1)

    # if doing the task earns more than not doing the task, return do_task
    if do_task > dont_do_task:
        path.append(n)
        return do_task

    # otherwise, return the value for not doing the task
    else:
        return dont_do_task


if __name__ == '__main__':
    task_list = [
        Tasks(1, 5, 1, 4),
        Tasks(2, 1, 3, 5),
        Tasks(3, 8, 0, 6),
        Tasks(4, 4, 4, 7),
        Tasks(5, 6, 3, 8),
        Tasks(6, 3, 5, 9),
        Tasks(7, 2, 6, 10),
        Tasks(8, 4, 8, 11)
    ]
    path = []
    get_max(3)
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to keep track of the **paths** (or schedules). If I call `get_max(8)`, I want to maintain a list that has 1, 4, and 8 not just the value that they combine to. I can't figure out how to use this function recursively while still tracking the paths that have been explored.

(side note: `get_max(0) = 0` so I will just write that as 0)

here's kind of a pseudocode of one example: get_max(3)

```
get_max(3)  
do_task = 8 + 0  
dont_task = get_max(2)
```

**makes the recursive call before it can finish:**

```
get_max(2)  
do_task = 1 + 0  
dont_task = get_max(1)
```

**makes the recursive call before it can finish:**

```
get_max(1)  
**do_task = 5 + 0**  
dont_do_task = get_max(0)
```

compares 5 and 0 and returns 5, so now:

```
get_max(2)  
do_task = 1 + get_max(0)  
**dont_do_task = 5**
```

compares 1 and 5 and returns 5, so now:

```
get_max(3)  
**do_task = 8 + get_max(0)**  
dont_do_task = 5
```

compares 8 and 5, 8 is greater

now at this point, I know I want to do task 3. So I would like to add 3 to the list of paths I'm going to take. However if I added something like

```
if doing path:  
    path_list.append(n)
```

then it also would've added 1 to the path list at from when I chose do_task in get_max(1) at the bottom of the recursion, which I don't want. Is there any way to ensure that I'm only adding the relevant paths to the list?

*EDIT*

For what it's worth, I did come up with a workaround but it's not very elegant, and it depends on calling get_max(n) in sequential order. (I also imported defaultdict from collections to make adding to the list easier)

```
def calculate():
    for i in range(numTasks):
        recursive_max(i + 1)

def get_max(n):

    if n == 0:
        return 0

    previous = prev(n)

    if previous in path_dict:
        do_task = value(n) + value_dict[previous][0]

    else:
        do_task = value(n) + get_max(previous)

    if n-1 in path_dict:
       dont_do_task = value_dict[n-1][0]
    else:
        dont_do_task = get_max(n - 1)

    if do_task > dont_do_task:
        if n not in path_dict:
            if previous > 0:
                for path in path_dict[previous]:
                    path_dict[n].append(path)

            path_dict[n].append(n)

            value_dict[n].append(do_task)

        return do_task

    # otherwise, return the value for not doing the task
    else:
        if n not in path_dict:

            for path in path_dict[n-1]:
                path_dict[n].append(path)

            value_dict[n].append(dont_do_task)

        return dont_do_task
```